# Google Big Query cloud storage path error

Tags: google-bigquery

I am brand new to google big query so apologize if this is obvious.

I am simply trying to test the product out right now. I am able to upload a 5 MB file without any issues.

When I move to 10 MB+ using google storage, I am having no luck.

I have a bucket named teststir and a file name verify_sift.csv

When I try to create a new data set I select google cloud and put:
gs://teststir/verify_sift.csv as the path.

Unfortunately the job keeps failing:
Not found: URI gs://teststir/verify_sift.csv

(I have triple checked names, tried multiple files but no luck). Am I missing something obvious? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Make sure you have GS under the same project.

Comment: I just loaded 2GB in data from a CVS file in GCS and is working just fine. Could you indicate the command you are using, mare sure you are authenticated with an user with permission on that bucket and that the bucket and the BQ dataset are under the same project as @Pentium10 suggested.

Comment: i am using the user interface of google BQ to upload data. it has a field for loading from google storage. this is where i type in gs://teststir/verify_sift.csv.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem.

I've just created new bucket with another location and it helped :)